# iOS 7 - game center leaderboard integration

Tags: ios, game-center

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forLeaderboardID: (NSString*) identifier
{
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier: identifier];
    scoreReporter.value = score;
    scoreReporter.context = 0;

    NSArray *scores = @[scoreReporter];
    [GKLeaderboard reportScores:scores withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    //Do something interesting here.
    }];
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html

On the above site, I used the above code (and the title was Reporting a score to Game Center (iOS 7)) but on the GKLeaderboard reportScores... line, I get an error saying that there is no such method. How do i fix this without using GKScore's deprecated reportScoreWithCompletionHandlerMethod?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So apple's thing had a typo. GKLeaderboard was supposed to be GKScore  in the reportScores line.